# Working with S3 buckets having no BucketName in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

Since the global uniqueness requirements of S3 bucket names, using the optional `BucketName` property in the `AWS::S3::Bucket` resource is problematic. Essentially, if I insist on using `BucketName` I need some way to attach a GUID there.

I can avoid this pain if I omit the `BucketName` property entirely, so CloudFormation reliably generates a unique name for me.

However, I face another problem: how do I work with this random bucket name in AWS Lambda/SAM/serverless.com/other code? I understand that CloudFormation templates can export the name, but how do I pass it to the Lambda code?

Is there a standard/recommended way of working with CloudFormation exports in AWS Lambda? The problem is not unique to S3 - e.g., AWS Amplify uses randomly generated DynamoDB table names, too.

Comment: Save the generated names into SSM parameter store and read the values from there when working with Lambda.

Answer (score 3):

- If your Lambda is created through CloudFormation, you can pass the bucket name using [Environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) (Environment key in [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-environment) and [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-environment)). You can refer to the bucket name using !Ref if the bucket is in the same spec and [cross stack references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) if using different stacks. If you use cross stack references, you won't be able to modify or delete the output value in the original stack until you remove all references to it. If you are using Ref, the Lambda will also be updated if the bucket name changes.
- If your Lambda isn't created through CloudFormation, you can use SSM parameter store as mentioned by Ervin in his comment. You can create a [SSM Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html) and read it's value in your Lambda code.